# Instrumental music playing in season 1 episode 5 when Kaneki & co. fighting Tsukiyama?

Tags: music, tokyo-ghoul

There's instrumental music playing in episode 5 of season 1 of *Tokyo Ghoul* at around 19:50 when Kaneki, Touka, and Nishiki are fighting Tsukiyama.

What is the title, and the name of the album if it exists?

Answer (score 2):

The sound track you are looking for is
 [東京喰種-トーキョーグール-](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3S1NmtWDVYk) Or [Licht und Schatten](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3S1NmtWDVYk) by [Yutaka Yamada](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/people.php?id=128448) Whom created most if not all of the music in tokyo ghoul.

The track is 4:15 long, and the instrumental part that can be heard around 19:50 into the 5th episode can be found at [3:48](https://youtu.be/3S1NmtWDVYk?t=228), The instrumental part that is

This track was included as 25th track on the 1st OST cd. The 2 ost CD's can be bought as a bundle from [cdjapan](http://www.cdjapan.co.jp/product/MJSA-1158) for around 28$